# Protected Custom settings in package

Tags: package, custom

[image]
We create a package . We have an issue with a **managed** triggered flow that need to access to a protected custom settings of the same package , in our Scratch org the flow work . When we create the package the flow fail , because we don't have access to the log or the flow interview, We used a field on the triggered object and we discovered that the flow failed to get the custom settings ... each flow that we created don't have access to the protected custom settings ...
on the image when you are on the Scrqtch org the flow work , when i go to a managed package the fault path is called ...the get action is the get of the custom protected setiings
can someone have a solution on this ???

Comment: What mode does the flow run in? Have you set it to System Mode with or without sharing, or is it running in User Mode?

Comment: it's a record triggered flow ,so it's in user mode

Comment: Given that constraint, perhaps you'll have to use some invokable method to get the protected settings? Yeah, you'd think a packaged flow would have package scope access, but it looks like you found a "bug" in the flow security implementation...?

Comment: yes ... maybe , I contacted SF we will see